# Prevent multiple vbModal dialog from showing in vba

Tags: vba, winapi

In Outlook, I have a macro that shows a vbModal form. User can run this macro as needed. Also, the macro is auto triggered where there is an incoming email. Thus it is possible to have two copies of the form showing; the user runs the macro just when there is an incoming email.

I like to prevent two or more copies of the form from showing, and used a mutex to control the macro, but it does not work and I need some help.

For debugging, I put the function `TestMutex Item` in `myOlSendItems_ItemAdd` and set an email to delay sent. After the email is sent, but still in the outbox, I manually run `TestMutex Item` and the dialog appears. I kept it on the screen. Once the delayed email timeout and sent, it triggered `myOlSendItems_ItemAdd` and call `TestMutex Item`.  Both these ran and two dialog boxes appeared. I was expecting `TestMutex Item` called by `myOlSendItems_ItemAdd` to pause at `WaitForSingleObject`  since I have yet to release the mutex but this did not happen. May I know how can I fix this?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateMutex Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateMutexA" (ByVal lpMutexAttributes As LongPtr, ByVal bInitialOwner As Long, ByVal lpName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenMutex Lib "kernel32" Alias "OpenMutexA" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal lpName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As LongPtr, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseMutex Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMutex As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long

Private Const INFINITE As Long = &HFFFFFFFF
Private Const ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS = 183&
Private Const MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0001
Private Const WAIT_OBJECT_0 As Long = &H0

Private mutex As LongPtr

Sub TestMutex(Item As Object)
Dim frmOptions As Object

    mutex = GetMutex()
    WaitForSingleObject mutex, INFINITE
     
    Set frmOptions = New frmSentEmail
    frmOptions.strSentTo = "Mutext testing"
    frmOptions.Show vbModal 
    
    ReleaseMutex mutex
    Debug.Print "Text Mutex ReleaseMutex", Item.Subject
End Sub


Function GetMutex() As LongPtr
Dim myMutex As LongPtr

    myMutex = CreateMutex(0, 1, "clSendOption")
    Dim er As Long: er = Err.LastDllError
    If er = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "clSendOption myMutex Created", myMutex
    ElseIf er = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS Then
        Debug.Print "clSendOption mutex previously created", myMutex
        myMutex = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, 0, "clSendOption")
    Else
        Debug.Print "clSendOption mutex creation failed"
    End If
    GetMutex = myMutex
Debug.Print Now, "Class_Initialize SendOptions Exit "

End Function
```

Comment: Wrong approach, a mutex is re-entrant on the same thread.  Since dialogs are displayed by code that runs on the one-and-only thread in VBA, the mutex won't block anything.  Would be rather harmful if it did, the program would deadlock and freeze.  Use a Boolean variable, what you'd do if it is True is not so obvious.  DoEvents is tricky to get right.